# Parole, entretien et causerie

Tags: vocabulaire

Il y a des mots dont je veux connaître les subtilités, à savoir *parole, entretien* et *causerie*. Je sais qu'il y a encore des mots  mais je ne les prendrai pas en compte pour raccourcir cette question un peu. Je vous fais part de mes pensées  en espérant que vous pourrez les améliorer.

Je vois le mot *parole* très souvent. Il convient pour décrire presque tout échange de mots entre deux ou plusieurs personnes.

Puis, on a le mot *entretien*. Je sais qu'on l'utilise plutôt pour le dépannage  d'un bâtiment ou quelque chose semblable, mais je l'ai trouvé dans un livre de Jules Verne avec le sens d'une parole, peu ou prou. Je crois qu'il vaut mieux utiliser ce mot s'il y a deux gens qui se connaissent déjà, et qui se mettent réciproquement au courant des nouveautés qu'ils ont vécu, de façon familière. Je ne sais pas s'il y a plus que deux gens qui parlent ensemble.

Quant au mot *causerie*, je pense que je l'ai aussi trouvé dans un ouvrage de Jules Verne. Le Wiktionnaire dit qu'une *causerie* est un *entretien*. Est-ce que je peux le dire lors d'une parole quelconque, ou diriez-vous que le mot lui-même est trop soutenu?

Que pensez-vous de la quantité de gens qui est requise pour l'emploi ces trois mots? Quels sont les sous-entendus que je dois connaître?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Votre question est centrée sur *la parole* dans le contexte de "l'expression *verbale* de la pensée".

C'est donc une pensée en action qui se formule dans l'oralité, qui est la base de la *conversation*, ce sont des phrases prononcées pour donner son opinion, discourir ou tenir des propos circonstanciés
... mais les *paroles en l'air* sont sans importance et ne doivent pas être prises en compte.

*L'entretien*, dans son sens second, est l' *action d'échanger des paroles avec une ou plusieurs personnes ; sujet dont on s'entretient.* ; avec comme synonyme *conversation, discussion*.
Il est souvent associé à embauche : obtenir un *entretien d'embauche* pour décrocher un emploi ; il sera souvent un *dialogue* entre le recruteur et le candidat.

S'il y a plusieurs personnes cela peut devenir un *colloque*, une *conférence*, un *débat*.

S'il est secret (et souvent mystérieux) c'est un *conciliabule*.

Mais une personnalité qui veut communiquer l’appellera *entrevue*, *interview*.

Un juge (et aussi  toute personne ayant la capacité de donner son avis) parlera *d'audience* car il voudra bien écouter ceux qui lui ont demandé un *entretien*.

Un *entretien* particulier sera un *tête-à-tête* ou une *aparté*.

Quant à la *causerie*, c'est un *entretien familier* ou un *discours, une conférence sans prétention*.

---

Références trouvées dans le Robert